# Need help porting this equation to java

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I'm trying to make a program that calculates the required score to level in a game and the equation works fine on my calculator but not when i try changing it to work with java.
the equation is **5,000 / 3 * (4n^3 - 3n^2 - n) + 1.25 * 1.8^(n - 60)** for example level 49 you should need to have a total score of 772240000 points and the calculator gives this answer  but my java program doesn't. here is the code i tried.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        double score = (double) ((5000 / 3) * (Math.pow(4 * i, 3) - Math.pow(3 * i, 2) - i) + (1.25 * Math.pow(1.8, i - 60)));
        System.out.println("Level " + i + " requires " + (long) score);
    }
```

This doesnt seem to work right and gives 12513130000 as the required points for lvl 49. If anyone can get it to work would you miind explaining what i did wrong.

Comment: `5000 / 3` is an integer division

Comment: You may as well remove the `double` cast. You're essentially saying `(double)(int * double + double)`, the result of what's in brackets is already `double`, so a cast won't do much. And enough people already mentioned the integer division issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're messing up your `Math.pow` calls, but you can avoid some of them entirely:

```
double score = (double) ((5000 / 3) * (4 * i * i * i - 3 * i * i - i) + (1.25 * Math.pow(1.8, i - 60)));
```

Here's what's wrong: `Math.pow(4 * i, 3)` is actually `(4i)^3` and **not** `4(i^3)`. To do the latter, you would need the following:

```
4 * Math.pow(i, 3)
```

I'm not entirely sure about the integer division part (you *are* casting it to `double`), but you may have to change `5000 / 3` to `5000.0 / 3`.

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly now after this and changing 5000 to 5000.0.

Comment: @Ephyxia That's great; since my answer solved your issue, would you mind accepting my answer?

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is inside Math.pow - you're multiplying your index value by a scalar each time.

```
4 * Math.pow(i, 3)
```

And

```
3 * Math.pow(i, 2)
```

Should fix it.

**Edit:** And the integer division mentioned in other answers.